# shortcut to copy the autocomplete result in chrome's launcher?

Tags: google-chrome

whenever you use chrome's launcher to do a calculation, such as put in "2+2="
it shows the result below it before you press enter.

how can I get this result into my clipboard the fastest, preferably without having to press enter and wait for a page refresh?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I mean, you're worried about the time it takes although the post back is likely much faster than it takes to type the query. I can't see why that is an issue which makes me think you may be trying to automate a process or similar?

Comment: Why are you doing this in Chrome? What OS is this for?

Comment: I want to use it as a feet-inches calculator, it's the fastest way to do it